# How can I make this smtplib code send emails in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, smtplib

How can I adjust the code below to send emails to the given recipient in an infinite loop?. I have tried below but I am getting an error:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.
with open(r'C:\Users\David\Documents\Hello.txt') as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'yes'
msg['From'] = "example1@hotmail.com"
msg['To'] = "example2@hotmail.com"

# Login
s =server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login('example1@hotmail.com',"password")

i = 0
while True:
# Sending the message
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()

i = i + 1
```

Comment: adjust your indentation, and provide us with your logs error.

Comment: why would you like to send emails in an infinite loop? that sounds like spam

Comment: I don't plan on spamming anyone else, only my own email. I'm just curious to see how the code would actually work.

Comment: your code has incorrect indentation. maybe having a code that actually runs will help. Also you know that as soon as your loops sends a few emails in a loop the office265 server will blacklist you preventing to send more emails right?

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. While loop not properly indented (but maybe that was a copy/paste formatting error into StackOveflow?)
2. SMTP connection is started once, before the loop but quit on every iteration within the loop. (Either keep it open for the whole loop or connnect and quit within each iteration).

Here's updated code (untested) with the above fixes:

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.
with open(r'C:\Users\David\Documents\Hello.txt') as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'yes'
msg['From'] = "example1@hotmail.com"
msg['To'] = "example2@hotmail.com"
    
i = 0
while True:
    # Login
    s =server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login('example1@hotmail.com',"password")

    # Sending the message
    s.send_message(msg)

    s.quit()  
    i = i + 1
```